# Apache Avro Array of Array of Records fails in Python ("unhashable type, dict") when loading schema

Tags: python, arrays, schema, avro

All,
I've had luck creating an Apache Avro schema with an array of records, but when I then try to make an array of an array of records, the python schema parser fails. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

```
    {
    "type": "record",
    "name": "userInfo",
    "namespace": "my.example",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "ID",
            "type": "string",
            "default": "NONE"
        },
        {
            "name": "message_timestamp",
            "type": "long"
        },
        {
            "name": "location",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
            ],
            "default": "NONE"
        },
        {
            "name": "AttributeMapping0",
            "type": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "timestamp",
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "AttributeMapping1",
                        "type": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "name": "AttributeMapping2",
                                    "type": "record",
                                    "fields": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "Name",
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "name": "Value",
                                            "type": "long"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The error message is very long - sorry:

```
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1283, in Parse
    return SchemaFromJSONData(json_data, names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1254, in SchemaFromJSONData
    return parser(json_data, names=names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1182, in _SchemaFromJSONObject
    other_props=other_props,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1061, in __init__
    fields = make_fields(names=nested_names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1173, in MakeFields
    return tuple(RecordSchema._MakeFieldList(field_desc_list, names))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 986, in _MakeFieldList
    yield RecordSchema._MakeField(index, field_desc, names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 957, in _MakeField
    names=names,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1254, in SchemaFromJSONData
    return parser(json_data, names=names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1197, in _SchemaFromJSONObject
    items=SchemaFromJSONData(items_desc, names),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1254, in SchemaFromJSONData
    return parser(json_data, names=names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1142, in _SchemaFromJSONArray
    return UnionSchema(map(MakeSchema, json_array))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 866, in __init__
    self._schemas = tuple(schemas)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1141, in MakeSchema
    return SchemaFromJSONData(json_data=desc, names=names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1254, in SchemaFromJSONData
    return parser(json_data, names=names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/avro_python3-1.8.0-py3.4.egg/avro/schema.py", line 1154, in _SchemaFromJSONObject
    if type in PRIMITIVE_TYPES:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a couple examples of what you'd like your records to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so honestly I'm still not particularly sure on why the schema above fails, but this answer was what I was looking for: [How to define avro schema for complex json document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163225/how-to-define-avro-schema-for-complex-json-document)

This answer here shows how to have an array of arrays of records. Just what I needed in my particular case.