# Elasticsearch type object for a string

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Here is a simplified version of my mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "user-event": {
            "_all": {
               "enabled": true
            },
            "properties": {
                "account_id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "payload": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Currently `payload` is a string, and this will be a stringified JSON payload, for instance: `"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"`

Is it possible to change the payload type to `JSON` so that ES automatically parses the string and so I can do query on `payload`?

If not, do I have to write raw JSON into ES to be able to query it?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you need to modify the way you're sending your data to ES: How do you send your documents to ES?

Comment: It's a downstream service I do not control. I write to a kafka stream, and that gets published into ES. How so do I need to modify what I write?

Comment: Can you modify the documents before writing to Kafka? Another way is to do it after Kafka, are you using Logstash to consume Kafka and send to ES?

Comment: @Val; so I do have a question about that. I have a `org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase` and this is the object I serialize and send to Kafka. Given avro does not have a generic `object` type, the `payload` type is set to `string`. So how can I write a json to kafka?

Comment: That leads to my second question: how are you consuming kafka?

Comment: You mean the consumer who then writes to ES? If so again that's downstream and I do not know. That service is not going to change. I believe they just write whatever is sent to kafka. So I need to write JSON to kafka to get that into ES.

Comment: You can then use a complex [Avro Record type](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#schema_complex) in order to encore your payload field. No need to store it as a JSON string. Some example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163225/how-to-define-avro-schema-for-complex-json-document

Comment: This works even if `payload` is not a of defined key/value pair? This payload could have any key/value of the user's chose

Comment: Well if you use Avro that's because you ideally want to keep some order in your data. If you let anything creep into your data, Avro is not really the best bet. What version of ES are you using?

Comment: @Val, yeah I know. I'm using 2.4.3

Comment: Until you upgrade to ES 5 where you can use pipeline processors in order to transform your docs before they get indexed, you could use the deprecated [transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/mapping-transform.html) feature in order to deserialize your JSON payload. That should work, although I've never tried it.

Comment: @Val, thanks! Will look into that

Comment: Is [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474464/elasticsearch-possible-to-search-through-string-json) related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ES don't have mapping type JSON, [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html) all available types. But you can change your mapping and use `nested` type for it, after that you have to re-index all your data and during this re-index you have to post not JSON string but JSON object, something like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/yourIndex/yourType/1 -d '{
    "account_id" : 1,
    "name" : "Admin",
    "payload": {"foo": "bar"}
}'
```

And everything will work!