# How to handle deserializing avro map type in C#

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

Working on a project using the .net confluent kafka client, getting an exception when deserializing an avro map type. Is there a way of doing this in c#?

The project is producing and consuming message from kafka. There are no issues around consuming anything other than map types.

Avro schema snippet:

```
  {
    "name": "DurationMargins",
    "type": {
      "type": "map",
      "values": {
        "type": "map",
        "values": "double"
      }
    }
  },
```

Avrogen creates the following property from this:

```
private IDictionary<string,IDictionary<string,System.Double>> _DurationMargins;
```

But when trying to consume the messages out of Kafka, receive the following exception:

```
Avro.AvroException : Unable to find type IDictionary<string,System.Double> in all loaded assemblies in field DurationMargins
```

Comment: why cant you de-serialize into a proper model class ?

Comment: Post your code. How did you try to deserialize the data? `IDictionary` is an *interface*, not a class that can be instantiated

Comment: Also post the *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. This includes the call stack and any inner exceptions which show *exactly* which method raised the exception. Both [Avro's](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/csharp/src/apache/main/Specific/ObjectCreator.cs) and [Cofluent Kafka's](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet) .NET source code is available on Github. You can check the method that threw to find out what it was expecting

Comment: And the Avro code doesn't seem to handle *nested maps*. Why are you using nested maps? If you want to store complex objects (JSON or not) you can use records. Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163225/how-to-define-avro-schema-for-complex-json-document)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah seems like the issue was nested maps. I've changed this to a map of records and it's de-serializing succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue because we were trying to use nested maps, as @PanagiotisKanavos.

Changing the schema to use a map of record types has fixed my issue.

Thanks for the help